# is it possible to use graphql without store data in data base?

Tags: python-3.x, graphql

hello I would like to know if it is possible to store data in a database with GraphQL using python without going through mongodb or sql?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. GraphQL doesn't care about the underlying database. You can connect to a csv file, a JSON file, a REST interface whatever.